# How do you hookup a mongo db for JEE6 project?

Tags: mongodb, java-ee-6, database

I'm trying to use my mongo db in replace of my current apache derby database. How do I connect my mongo db up to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Mongo has a java driver, and examples on how to use it. 
Look at [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial) tutorial. 
In addition, I would recommend you to define a data access layer with DAO interfaces so you will have loose coupling between the data access code and the business logic code, so if you need to replace again the DB,
 you will replace only the DAL implementation and not touch the BLL code